How to multiply structures among themselves
I need to multiply the structures among themselves and write the result into a separate one. The problem is that after multiplication it is impossible to transmit the result. If I transfer the result to an already initialized one, the values ​​​​in it do not change. And if it’s uninitialized, then just 0
include /masm64/include64/masm64rt.inc

multiply_vectors proto p_base: qword, p_vector1: ptr vector6, p_vector2: ptr vector6, p_result: ptr vector6



MSGBOXPARAMS struct
    cbSize dword ?, ?
    hwndOwner qword ?
    hInstance qword ?
    lpszText qword ?
    lpszCaption qword ?
    dwStyle dword ?, ?
    lpszIcon qword ?
    dwContextHelpId qword ?
    lpfnMsgBoxCallback qword ?
    dwLanguageId dword ?, ?
MSGBOXPARAMS ends

vector6 struct
    x0 qword ?
    x1 qword ?
    x2 qword ?
    x3 qword ?
    x4 qword ?
    x5 qword ?
vector6 ends

IRS struct
    s_name dq ?
    s_profit dq ?
    s_tax dq ?
    s_count_fine dq ?
IRS ends


.const
    IDI_ICON equ 1001
    columns_count equ 6
    fmt0 db "New matrix:", 10,
            "|%3d, %3d, %3d, %3d, %3d, %3d|", 10,
            "|%3d, %3d, %3d, %3d, %3d, %3d|", 10,
            "Result 1: %d",10,
            "Result 2: %d",0
.data
    ; Matrix 6?6
    row0 vector6 <1,  4, 3,   9, 49, 48>
    row1 vector6 <1,  1, 3,  16,  7, 30>
    row2 vector6 <7, 51, 1, 333,  63, 8>
    row3 vector6 <1,  4, 3,   9, 49, 48>
    row4 vector6 <1,  1, 3,  16,  7, 30>
    row5 vector6 <7, 51, 1, 333,  63, 8>

    row2_0 vector6 <1,  4, 3,   9, 49, 48>
    row2_1 vector6 <1,  1, 3,  16,  7, 30>
    row2_2 vector6 <7, 51, 1, 333,  63, 8>
    row2_3 vector6 <1,  4, 3,   9, 49, 48>
    row2_4 vector6 <1,  1, 3,  16,  7, 30>
    row2_5 vector6 <7, 51, 1, 333,  63, 8>

    t_res qword ?

    row_res0 vector6 <?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>
    row_res1 vector6 <?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>
    row_res2 vector6 <?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>
    row_res3 vector6 <?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>
    row_res4 vector6 <?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>
    row_res5 vector6 <?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>

    
    
    res dq 0

    irsArray IRS <1000, 100, 3, 20>, <1001, 110, 4, 23> , <10002, 0, 2, 19> , <1003, 50, 5, 21>
    arrSize equ ($-irsArray) / type IRS
    average_profit dq 0
    res2 dq 0
    
    params0 MSGBOXPARAMS <>
    title0 db "MessageBox", 0
    text0 db 1024 dup(0)
.code
entry_point proc

    invoke multiply_vectors, 0, addr row2_0, addr row0, addr row_res0
    invoke multiply_vectors, 0, addr row2_1, addr row1, addr row_res1
    invoke multiply_vectors, 0, addr row2_2, addr row2, addr row_res2
    invoke multiply_vectors, 0, addr row2_3, addr row3, addr row_res3
    invoke multiply_vectors, 0, addr row2_4, addr row4, addr row_res4
    invoke multiply_vectors, 0, addr row2_5, addr row5, addr row_res5  


    invoke wsprintf, addr text0, addr fmt0, row_res0.x0, row_res0.x1, row_res0.x2, row_res0.x3, row_res0.x4, row_res0.x5, row_res1.x0, row_res1.x1, row_res1.x2, row_res1.x3, row_res1.x4, row_res1.x5, 0, res2
    mov params0.cbSize, sizeof MSGBOXPARAMS
    mov params0.hwndOwner, 0
    invoke GetModuleHandle, 0
    mov params0.hInstance, rax
    lea rax, text0
    mov params0.lpszText, rax
    lea rax, title0
    mov params0.lpszCaption, rax
    mov params0.dwStyle, MB_USERICON
    mov params0.lpszIcon, IDI_ICON
    mov params0.dwContextHelpId, 0
    mov params0.lpfnMsgBoxCallback, 0
    mov params0.dwLanguageId, LANG_NEUTRAL
    lea rcx, params0
    invoke MessageBoxIndirect
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
entry_point endp

multiply_vectors proc p_base: qword, p_vector1: ptr vector6, p_vector2: ptr vector6, p_result: ptr vector6

    lea rsi, p_vector1         
    lea rdi, p_vector2        
    lea rdx, p_result         
    mov rcx, columns_count    

    xor rax, rax               
loop_multiply:
    mov r8, qword ptr [rsi + (rax*8)]   
    mov r9, qword ptr [rdi + (rax*8)]      

    imul r8, r9                  
    mov qword ptr [rdx + rax*8], r8  

    inc rax                    
    cmp rax, rcx               
    jnl loop_multiply          

    ret
multiply_vectors endp
end


All your p_ parameters are pointers. You need to use mov not lea.

Get to know the addresses of your important data structures to learn what various kinds of (good) pointers look like, so that when you're single stepping in the debugger, you'll know right away if there's a bad pointer in a register, or passed as a parameter.
